# CSS: Float elements inside div which fills the remaining space horizontally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to float elements inside middle div which fills the remaining space horizontally. The crDiv should float left to symDiv.Currently it is coming on the next line.

```
.tContainer{
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.parentDiv{
  width: 100%
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pointerLeft{
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.checkBoxDiv{
  float: right;
  width: 16px;
}

.eleDiv{
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tContainer">
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pointerLeft"></div>
    <div class="checkBoxDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBox" name="CheckBox">    
  </div>
    <div class="eleDiv">
        <div class="symDiv">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
        <div class="crDiv">
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pointerright"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

what i want : 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iBig.png)

what i am getting : 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLXxqJ

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want, but sounds a lot like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can help you here.

Comment: i want crDiv next to symDiv but it is coming on next line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex` CSS to achieve this:

```
.eleDiv {    
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following CSS rule:

```
.crDiv , .symDiv {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap grid to put a size on your elements
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Comment: while the link might provide the answer, it's best to post any relevant part of the post in your answer must the link ever die.

Comment: If he doesn't use BS so far (would be visible in the code) It's not the best idea to use entire framework just to get this one thing right

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanna?

```
<div class="tContainer">
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pointerLeft"></div>
    <div class="checkBoxDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBox" name="CheckBox">    
  </div>
    <div class="eleDiv">
        <div class="symDiv">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
        <div class="crDiv">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pointerright"/> D
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>


.tContainer{
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display:block;
}

.parentDiv{
  width: 100%
  display:block;
}

.pointerLeft{
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.checkBoxDiv{
  float: right;
  width: 16px;
}

.eleDiv{
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.symDiv{
  float: right;
  width: 90%
}

.crDiv{
  float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq5z848e/)

I put the letter D instead binding the glyphicon but it should be OK.